# When to use wrong or wrongly as adverbs?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

It seems that *wrong* is not only an adjective, but is also a proper adverb ("You're doing it wrong!", right?). There's, however, an adverb *wrongly*, which probably means the same thing.

Talking about **adverbs**, when does one use *wrong* or *wrongly*?

Comment: Just because *wrongly* exists does not mean that *wrong* does not exist as an adverb.  Which came first, wrong (adv.) or wrong (adv.)?  That's a question for folks with better dictionaries than me.

Comment: *"He entered the data wrong":* he entered incorrect data; *"He entered the data wrongly":* he entered data in an incorrect manner.

Comment: @PeterShor *"He entered the data wrong": he entered incorrect data;* that's just so wrong in pragmatics.

Comment: See also: *bad* and *good* used as adjectives and as adverbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it bears noting that dictionaries have been reporting both *wrong* and *wrongly* as legitimate adverbs since Samuel Johnson's first *Dictionary of the English Language* (1756)—and the usage undoubtedly goes much farther back than that.

I suspect that the choice between *wrong* and *wrongly* is idiosyncratic at many points and involves a lot of overlap. Nevertheless, there are some cases where a great majority of native English speakers would almost certainly choose one over the other. For example, *wrongly* is surely the normal choice in a sentence such as this:

> He **wrong/wrongly** interpreted the stranger's comment as an insult.

On the other hand, *wrong* seems clearly preferable in this case:

> The victim never understood what he had done **wrong/wrongly**.

And again here:

> Don't get me **wrong/wrongly**—I love okra when it isn't slimy and revolting.

Having said that, I acknowledge that shorter-form adverbs have grown more popular in recent years, as people have adopted adjective-lookalike forms in situations where teachers and commentators traditionally preferred *-ly* forms. In this connection, it's interesting that the same guy who approved an ad campaign based on the slogan "Think different" was also famous for telling people who had trouble with signal reception on his company's phone, "You're holding it wrong." I would have used *differently* in the first instance and *wrong* in the second, but I wouldn't argue that *wrongly* was wrong in the latter instance.

Comment: Thank you! Not being a native speaker, I'm glad to see that I have developed similar intuition. I wonder, though, if it can be codified somehow

Comment: "He ... interpreted the stranger's comment as an insult." *wrong/wrongly* are not interchangeable -- the sentence does not mean the same in the two cases at all.

Comment: @Kris, Sven Yargs pointed it out: "*wrongly* is surely the normal choice ... "

Comment: @Mari-LouA When that is what is meant. Not when *wrong* is meant to be said.